# Unexpected error while subscribing to IBM Mobile First push

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

i'm trying to set up IBM Mobile First Push Notifications.

I'm using Mobile First Platform 7.1.0.00.20151107-1653

What i did so far:

- Created apns sandbox certificate and included it into the root folder of the app.
- Added configuration in application-descriptor.xml
- Entered Push Code into my adapter like described in https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/EventSourceNotifications/blob/release71/adapters/PushAdapter/PushAdapter-impl.js
- Added Push initialization function into my client app:

  ```
   var isPushSupported = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
   if (isPushSupported) {
      WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
         "myPush",
         "MetaAdapter",
         "PushEventSource");

      WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
         onSuccess: function(){
            alert("success");
         },
         onFailure: function(errorMsg){
            alert(JSON.stringify(errorMsg));
         }
      });

   }else{
      console.log('---> Push not supported by device')
   }
  ```

After that i pushed the code on my server (which was also no problem) i tried to start the app. At the app start there was the typical "Do you want to allow Push Notifications for this app" question which i allowed.

Now when the posted code is executed the onFailure error message is shown with a `500 - Unexpected Error`.

In the XCode Console i can see the following output:

```
{"errors":["A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR 'APP_NAME\/1.0.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.1; Scale\/2.00),Ma&' to length 254. 
{prepstmnt 772646547 INSERT INTO PUSH_DEVICES (CREATED_MODE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, APPLICATION_ID, DEVICE_ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, PUSH_KEY, LATITUDE, LOCALE, LONGITUDE, PLATFORM, STATUS, TOKEN, USER_AGENT, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
[params=(String) API, (String) 2015-11-30T19:56:15Z, (String) 2015-11-30T19:56:15Z, (String) app_identifier, (String) 54D7CA02-64BA-4644-85E2-B29A0811FE6B, (String)
app_identifier-1.0.0, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (null) null, (String) A, (int) 0, (String) ef65cf4638308d13de9af9e09704cfdd9fe1010d3dcd678feb2aa8cf61a4b855, (String) 
APP_NAME\/1.0.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.1; Scale\/2.00),APP_NAME..., 
(String) 6dcd1097-1aa0-4111-af44-3234c29079e0]} [code=20000, state=22001]"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
```

The APP_NAME is 21 characters long and the app_identifier is 52 characters long.

Do you have any ideas to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something that needs investigation. If you are IBM customer or Business Partner, I suggest you open a PMR.